# Can I get value from a variable and use it on a specific index of a different variable?

Tags: modeling, constraint

This is a peculiar question but I have two variables $s_{ik}$ (integer) and $y_{it}$ (binary). What I want is the following relationship: If $s_{ik} = 8$, then $y_{i8} = 1$.

Basically, if $s_{ik}$ takes a particular value then $y_{it}$ where $t = s_{ik}$ should be $1$, otherwise $y_{it}$ should be $0$. Is this thing possible?

Comment: Do you have other constraints on $y_{it}$, like maybe $\sum_t y_{it} = 1$ for all $i$?

Comment: Since $y_{it}$ does not have a subscript $k,$ are you looking to enforce this relationship for one specific value of $k$ (meaning there is no relationship between $s_{ij}$ and $y_{it}$ when $j\neq k$)?

Comment: The variable s_ik represents the time value of a specific combination of (i,k) and the variable y_it represents binary value for that time value. I have an objective function that in terms of y_it because it represents that rewards for (i,t) pair. But the constraints do not have any relationship for y_it, so I am trying to create one.

Comment: Also just wanted to add what kind of work I have done so far: 
One constraint that works when $s_ik <= t$ is 
$y_it <= s_ik/t$
I am not sure whether this kind of setup is acceptable but I don't there should be any problem for gurobi at least. 
The problem is that this constraint cannot capture the idea when $s_it > t$. In this case the y_it should still be 0 but I don't know how to capture this. Essentially for more clarification, y_it should only have value = 1 when $t = s_it$. For every other case, $y_it = 0$

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
\sum_t y_{it} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$}\\
\sum_t t y_{it} &= s_{ik} &&\text{for all $i$ and $k$}
\end{align}